# An error occurred with <appName> when connecting to Facebook

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to connect to facebook to authenticate users but in facebook's login dialog I get the following message:
An error occurred with . Please try again later.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the following line from FB.init()

```
xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
```

It worked for me. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the error message *'Error occured ! please try again'* after we try to relogin. we have to give `appid` in two places in `Facebook/index.php` page.

first one in

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'your_app_id',
  'secret' => 'your_secret_id',
  'cookie' => true,
));
```

but after giving the missing second one i get rid of the problem

```
src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=your_app_id&amp;xfbml=1"
```

But still it works for me!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was caused by request for invalid scope/permission (location instead of user_location).